# Basis of the subspace $\{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 \in \mathbb{R}_3[x] \mid a_0+a_3=a_1+a_2\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

I was requested to find the basis of the subspace $\{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 \in \mathbb{R}_3[x] :~a_0+a_3=a_1+a_2\}$. I am unsure of whether my result is correct, mainly because this is the first time I directly deal with polynomial rings.

What seems correct to me is to say

$$\begin{align}f(x) &= a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 \\&= (a_1+a_2-a_3)+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 \\&= a_1(1  +x) +a_2(1 + x^2)-a_3(1+x^3) \\ \implies \dim(S)&=3 \end{align}$$

In other words, one may note any $f$ might be expressed as a linear combination of the three vectors (polynomial functions, in this case)

$$\begin{cases} f_1 =1+x \\ f_2 = 1+x^2 \\ f_3 = 1+x^3 \end{cases}$$

where the set $\{f_1, f_2, f_3\}$ is linearly independent. Is this correct?

Comment: Your $f_3$ is not in the space, since it has $a_0+a_3=2 \neq a_1+a_2=0$. But this is just because of a simple error; your approach is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. It should be:$$f(x)=a_{1}(1+x)+a_{2}(1+x^2)\color{red}{+}a_{3}(-1+x^{3}).$$
With that correction, everything else you wrote is correct. Recall that we says that $f\in {\bf R}_n[x]$ is linear combination of a set $\{f_1,\ldots, f_n\}\subset {\bf R }_n[x]$ iff there exists scalars $a_1,\ldots, a_n\in {\bf R}$ such that $f=\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}} a_i f_i$.

Comment: Thanks! That is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It is. You made a careless mistake on $f_3$.  It should be $x^3-1$.

To prove linear independence:   $b_1f_1+b_2f_2+b_3f_3=0\implies b_1+b_2-b_3+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3=0\implies b_1=b_2=b_3=0$, since a third degree polynomial has at most $3$ roots.

Comment: Thanks you so much!